# Is this solution for combinatorics problem correct?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of five-letter word that use letters from the alphabet $\{A,B,C\}$ and include at least one A and at least one B.

My approach to solve the problem is like :

For two place we should have at lest one $A$ and one $B$ and they can appear in $2!$ order.

And these two letters can appear in any of the $2$ of $5$ places. So ${5 \choose 2}$.

And for remaining $3$ places we have $3^3$ possibilities.

Hence the answer is : $2! * {5 \choose 2} * 3^3$

Is my solution correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Say X is a set of words without letter A and Y without leter B. Then $|X|=|Y|=2^5$ and $ |X\cap Y|= 1$. Since all words is $3^5$ the answer is $3^5-2^6+1$

Comment: what's wrong with my counting method ? can you explain.

Comment: @user292174 You're double counting if for example there are two $A$'s and one $B$. Which $A,B$ pair is the one you start with in your counting?